# What is a good way to extend a list with a repeated number?

Tags: python

I want to extend a list with the number 2450, 50 times. What is a good way to do this?

```
for e in range(0,50):
    L2.extend(2450)
```

Answer (score 9):

This will add `2450`, 50 times.
`l2.extend([2450]*50)`

Example:

```
>>> l2 = []
>>> l2.extend([2450]*10)
>>> l2
[2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450]
```

Or better yet:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> l2 = []
>>> l2.extend(repeat(2450,10))
>>> l2
[2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450, 2450]
```